# Sending file to multiple contact's resources

Tags: resources, xmpp, file-transfer, socks

Are there existing practices / XMPP extensions to send a file to several contact's online resources via relay (SOCKS5) server?

Use-case explanation:
Alice (alice@example.com) wants to send a file to Bob (bob@example.com). Alice is behind NAT and Firewall. Bob has two XMPP clients, both online (each with different resource - bob@example.com/first and bob@example.com/second). Both support xep-0065 (for instance). Alice sends file transfer request to Bob, Bob accepts it on one of his devices, the file is being transferred through relay (relay.example.com) to both Bob's clients.

```
         alice@example.com
                \/
         relay.example.com
          \/           \/       
bob@example.com/first  bob@example.com/second
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no such XMPP extensions for this use case.

I'd recommend you store the file on an http server (Amazon S3 comes to mind) and send the download link to all connected resources of the recipient. Upon successful reception acknowledged by the resources, the sender can delete the file.

There will be additional negociation between the recipient resources (1 resource would say to the other: "I have accepted the file transfer, please download it too")